# Getting PNGs from JSON

Tags: c#, json, unity-game-engine

//THESE ARE THE 3 SCRIPTS THAT I HAVE. In the BookCovers I parse the JSON and in the CustomCell I assign the values to the Label. Then in the ListSource I assign each Label to the current row.

//THIS IS BOOKCOVERS.CS

```
 public ListSource dataSource;
    public ArrayList coversURL;
    public WWW imageURLWWW;

    public IEnumerator FetchBooks()
    {
        //A URL where the image is stored
        string url = "http: myLink";  

        //Call the WWW class constructor
        imageURLWWW = new WWW(url);
        Debug.Log ("blla blla blla");
        yield return imageURLWWW;

        JsonData imageUrls = JsonMapper.ToObject(imageURLWWW.text);
        print (imageUrls);

        coversURL = new ArrayList ();

        for (int i = 0; i < imageUrls.Count; i++) 
        {  
            JsonData book = imageUrls [i];
            string url1 = (string) book ["url_cover_img"];
            coversURL.Add (url1);
        }

        updateSurce ();
        foreach (string urls in coversURL) {

            Debug.Log (urls);
        }
        Debug.Log ("Fetch is completed");

        Debug.Log ("Update Source");
        dataSource.sourcce = coversURL;
        Debug.Log ("Size " + dataSource.sourcce.Count);
        dataSource.tableView.ReloadData ();


    }
```

//THIS IS CUSTOMCELL.CS

```
  using UnityEngine;
    using System.Collections;
    using Tacticsoft;
    using UnityEngine.UI;

public class CustomCell : TableViewCell {

    public Text label1;

    void Start()
    {
        label1 = (Text)GetComponent<Text> ();
    }

}
```

//THIS IS THE LIST SOURCE.CS

```
 public TableViewCell GetCellForRowInTableView(TableView tableView, int row)
        {
            CustomCell cell = tableView.GetReusableCell("asdasdasds") as CustomCell;
            if (cell == null) 
            {
                cell = (CustomCell)GameObject.Instantiate(cellType);

            }

            Debug.Log ("Get cells");
            cell.label1.text=(string)sourcce[row];
            return cell;
        }
```

Comment: so... are you trying to assign a PNG to a text label?

Comment: I did it just to show the string files in my listview in Unity. Do you have an idea how can I show the PNG files just as I show the string files in my listview

Comment: you can get texture from online or local storage with [WWW.texture](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/WWW-texture.html) it will give you Texture2D object.

Comment: you can't use "arraylist" in Unity, change over to ordinary List<>.  It causes some confusion that there is some (very old) example code on the net wit arraylist. As a rule in Unity you never really use array, just use List<> (and never use "arraylist")

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion